# Blazor project is not working (.NET6). What's the problem with the Lifetime cycle/Mapping?

Tags: .net-6.0, blazor-webassembly, automapping

I have a Blazor project (Webassembly)

I want to start the application and it ends with an error message in program.cs
**on line: var app = builder.Build();**

```
using myWebapp.Blazor.Server.Data;
using myWebapp.Blazor.Server.Models;
using myWebappData;
using myWebappService.Configuration;
using myWebappService.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.ResponseCompression;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
//var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
//builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
//    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();
builder.Services.AddDbContext<efmDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(
                    connectionString: builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

//RegisterDependencyServiceServiceLayer.ConfigureService(builder.Services);
builder.Services.AddTransient<IMyIndexService, MyIndexService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IMyViewsService, MyViewsService>();
builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<ApplicationUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddIdentityServer()
    .AddApiAuthorization<ApplicationUser, ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddAuthentication()
    .AddIdentityServerJwt();

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
    app.UseWebAssemblyDebugging();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseBlazorFrameworkFiles();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseIdentityServer();
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapRazorPages();
app.MapControllers();
app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");

app.Run();
```

This is included:

```
<PackageReference Include="AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection" Version="6.1.1" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Server" Version="6.0.8" />
```

This is the message:

System.AggregateException: 'Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: myWebappService.Services.IMyIndexService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: myWebappService.Services.MyIndexService': Unable to resolve service for type 'AutoMapper.IMapper' while attempting to activate 'myWebappService.Services.MyIndexService'.) (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: myWebappService.Services.IMyViewsService Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: myWebappService.Services.MyViewsService': Unable to resolve service for type 'AutoMapper.IMapper' while attempting to activate 'myWebappService.Services.MyViewsService'.)'

InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'AutoMapper.IMapper' while attempting to activate 'myWebappService.Services.MyIndexService'.

Comment: `builder.Services.AddAutoMapper();`  or something like that. RTFM.

Comment: Yes I forget the AddAutoMapper command and the reference AutoMapper (without IndependancyInjection).

Answer (score 0):

The system cannot create the instance for the services that you declared.

Try to add this code to your program.cs

```
    builder.Services.AddScoped<AutoMapper>();
or
    builder.Services.AddScoped<MyIndexService>();
```

Where "AutoMapper" or "MyIndexService" are the classes that seems to have issues.